# the output of py command is the same as pip command

Tags: python, compiler-errors

when I want to compile my python code, I can't becose it apparently not the good arguments, Example I have a main.py and I do py main.py and it output an thing that I don't care about:

```
py main.py
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.

Usage:
  main.py <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  show                        Show information about installed packages.
  check                       Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.
  config                      Manage local and global configuration.
  search                      Search PyPI for packages.
  cache                       Inspect and manage pip's wheel cache.
  index                       Inspect information available from package indexes.
  wheel                       Build wheels from your requirements.
  hash                        Compute hashes of package archives.
  completion                  A helper command used for command completion.
  debug                       Show information useful for debugging.
  help                        Show help for commands.

General Options:
  -h, --help                  Show help.
  --debug                     Let unhandled exceptions propagate outside the main subroutine, instead of logging them
                              to stderr.
  --isolated                  Run pip in an isolated mode, ignoring environment variables and user configuration.
  --require-virtualenv        Allow pip to only run in a virtual environment; exit with an error otherwise.
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
  -V, --version               Show version and exit.
  -q, --quiet                 Give less output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times (corresponding to
                              WARNING, ERROR, and CRITICAL logging levels).
  --log <path>                Path to a verbose appending log.
  --no-input                  Disable prompting for input.
  --proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
  --retries <retries>         Maximum number of retries each connection should attempt (default 5 times).
  --timeout <sec>             Set the socket timeout (default 15 seconds).
  --exists-action <action>    Default action when a path already exists: (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup,
                              (a)bort.
  --trusted-host <hostname>   Mark this host or host:port pair as trusted, even though it does not have valid or any
                              HTTPS.
  --cert <path>               Path to PEM-encoded CA certificate bundle. If provided, overrides the default. See 'SSL
                              Certificate Verification' in pip documentation for more information.
  --client-cert <path>        Path to SSL client certificate, a single file containing the private key and the
                              certificate in PEM format.
  --cache-dir <dir>           Store the cache data in <dir>.
  --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
  --disable-pip-version-check
                              Don't periodically check PyPI to determine whether a new version of pip is available for
                              download. Implied with --no-index.
  --no-color                  Suppress colored output.
  --no-python-version-warning
                              Silence deprecation warnings for upcoming unsupported Pythons.
  --use-feature <feature>     Enable new functionality, that may be backward incompatible.
  --use-deprecated <feature>  Enable deprecated functionality, that will be removed in the future.
```

Oh and also I tried to uninstall and reinstall python, then I tried the one of the Microsoft Store but it doesn't work and then I just reinstall the one in the official website, but it never worked

Probably what happend is that I've somewhat mixed pip with py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question for now its useless, now it is fix and IDK how

Answer (score 0):

If the `py` command doesn’t work, try using a command like `python` or `python3`.

For example: `python main.py`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: Did you install the latest version of Python?